# Turning an image into grayscale and Deuteranomaly scale in Matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, rgb, photo, image-manipulation

I want to turn an image from its original RGB scale to grayscale and deuteranomaly. However, every attempt I try gives me somewhat darker image that does not truly display grayscale.[My attempt  for grayscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nvZs.png)
here is what im running

```
whe = imread('CoWheel.png');

whesi = size(whe);


red = [];
gree = [];
blue = [];

for i = 1:whesi(1)
    for j = 1:whesi(2)
        red(i,j) = whe(i,j,1);
        gree(i,j) = whe(i,j,2);
        blue(i,j) = whe(i,j,3);
    end
end

gray = whe;
for i = 1:whesi(1)
    for j = 1:whesi(2)

        gray(i,j,1) = gray(i,j,1)*.2989;
        gray(i,j,2) = gray(i,j,2)*.5870;
        gray(i,j,3) = gray(i,j,3)*.1141;

    end
```

And as for the deuteranomaly, I would have no clue into what to do to make that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is scaling `gray(i,j,1)`, `gray(i,j,2)`, `gray(i,j,3)`.
You need to scale and sum RGB elements: `gray = R*.2989 + G*.5870 + B*.1141`.

Here is a corrected code sample:

```
whe = imread('CoWheel.png');
figure;imshow(whe);

whesi = size(whe);


%You don'y use red, green and blue in your conversion code...
% red = [];
% gree = [];
% blue = [];
% 
% for i = 1:whesi(1)
%     for j = 1:whesi(2)
%         red(i,j) = whe(i,j,1);
%         gree(i,j) = whe(i,j,2);
%         blue(i,j) = whe(i,j,3);
%     end
% end

%Convert from uint8 to double (for performing the computations in double - not in uint8 integers).
whe = double(whe);

%gray = whe;

%The Grayscale image has only one color channel (not 3 like RGB)
gray = zeros(whesi(1), whesi(2));

for i = 1:whesi(1)
    for j = 1:whesi(2)
        gray(i,j) = whe(i,j,1)*.2989 + whe(i,j,2)*.5870 + whe(i,j,2)*.1141;
    end
end

%Convert from double to uint8
gray = uint8(gray);

figure;imshow(gray)
```

Result:
[image]

---

You can also use `rgb2gray`:

```
%Using MATLAB rgb2gray built in function:
whe = imread('CoWheel.png');
gray = rgb2gray(whe);
```

---

The rgb2gray is not the perceptual accurate.
In case you want an accurate result, you need to reverse gamma, compute Y (of XYZ color space, and apply gamma).

Shortcut: convert RGB to LAB, zero A and B, and convert to LAB to RGB:

```
RGB = whe;
LAB = rgb2lab(RGB); %Convert RGB to LAB
LAB(:,:,2) = 0; %Zero A channel
LAB(:,:,3) = 0; %Zero B channel
gray = lab2rgb(LAB); %The result is Grayscale image in RGB format (where R=G=B).
gray = im2uint8(gray); %Convert from range [0, 1] to uint8 [0, 255].
figure;imshow(gray)
```

Result:
[image]

Here is the RGB image, the first Grayscale result and perceptual accurate result:
[image]

---

As to Deuteranomaly, it requires some more research...

The following example is probably wrong, but I think it's in the right direction:

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness#Causes):

> Anomalous trichromacy is a common type of inherited color vision deficiency, occurring when one of the three cone pigments is altered in its spectral sensitivity.
>
> Protanomaly is a mild color vision defect in which an altered spectral sensitivity of red retinal receptors (closer to green receptor response) results in poor red–green hue discrimination.  It is hereditary, sex-linked, and present in 1% of males.
>   In contrast to other defects, in this case the L-cone is present but malfunctioning, whereas in protanopia the L-cone is completely missing.
>
> **Deuteranomaly**, caused by a similar shift in the green retinal receptors, is by far the most common type of color vision deficiency, mildly affecting red–green hue discrimination in 5% of European males.  It is hereditary and sex-linked.  In contrast to deuteranopia, the green-sensitive cones are not missing but malfunctioning.

I tried simulated Deuteranomaly, by reducing the intensity level of the **M-cone** (green) response.

I downloaded [Colorspace Transformations](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28790-colorspace-transformations) from File Exchange.

I used `colorspace` for converting RGB to [LMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMS_color_space) color space and from LMS to RGB.

Here is a code sample:

```
RGB = imread('CoWheel.png');
RGB = im2double(RGB); %Convert from uint8 [0,255] to double range [0, 1].

%Convert from RGB to LMS color space
LMS = colorspace('CAT02 LMS<-RGB', RGB);

%Reduce the M Cone intensity by half
LMS(:, :, 2) = LMS(:, :, 2)*0.5;

%Convert from LMS to RGB color space
deuteranomalyRGB = colorspace('RGB<-CAT02 LMS', LMS);

figure;imshow(deuteranomalyRGB)
```

Result:
[image]